# Pythonize function applied across columns in a pandas.Dataframe object

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, dataframe, list-comprehension

The following lines convert all columns in a `pandas.Dataframe` object to numeric.

```
columns = ['a', 'b']
dft = pd.DataFrame(data=[['1','2'], ['3','4'],['5','6']], columns=columns)
for col in columns:
    dft[col] = pd.to_numeric(dft[col])
```

That works well, but `for ... in:` is ugly.

How can I say use a `lambda` function and or a `list comprehension` to get this loop working in a single line?

(I have tried many things, but I couldn't find out how to assign the result from `pd.to_numeric()` to the variable name for each column in the dataframe)

Comment: *"`for ... in:` is ugly"* - looks fine to me. It's clear what's going on, and not clear why you think there's a problem!

Comment: Do you want to convert all columns or only certain ones?

Comment: here it happens that these are all columns, but I actually want to convert (only) columns in a given list of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution in [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11221#issuecomment-158422052).

```
print dft
print dft.dtypes
#   a  b  c
#0  1  2  5
#1  3  4  7
#2  5  6  9
#a    object
#b    object
#c    object
#dtype: object

dft1 = dft.apply(pd.to_numeric)

print dft1
print dft1.dtypes
#   a  b  c
#0  1  2  5
#1  3  4  7
#2  5  6  9
#a    int64
#b    int64
#c    int64
#dtype: object

dft[['a', 'b']] = dft[['a', 'b']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
print dft
print dft.dtypes
#   a  b  c
#0  1  2  5
#1  3  4  7
#2  5  6  9
#a     int64
#b     int64
#c    object
#dtype: object
```

Next solution is use `convert_objects`, but it raise error (v 0.17.0):

```
dft.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

> FutureWarning: convert_objects is deprecated.  Use the data-type specific converters pd.to_datetime, pd.to_timedelta and pd.to_numeric.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`dft = dft.applymap(lambda x: int(x))`

For the record `applymap` is used to apply a lambda function elementwise ([documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html))

**Edit**

A second way would be to do:

`dft=dft.astype(int)`

I haven't timed the approaches. I think however the second way is more *pandaic*